# Can we draw multiple textures in single gl.drawElements() call?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

In WebGL, can we draw multiple textures in single gl.drawElements() call? If yes how?

What is the use of `gl.TEXTURE0` to `gl.TEXTURE31`, I mean, What is the scenario when more than one texture units are used?

I'm trying to draw a cube with 6 different textures for each side in single drawElements() call. Is it possible? Is yes, How?

Answer (score 3):

To use multiple textures you bind different textures to different texture units and reference them with multiple samplers in your shaders

Here's a shader that uses 2 textures

```
 uniform sampler2D u_texture1;
 uniform sampler2D u_texture2;
 varying vec2 vtexcoords1;
 varying vec2 vtexcoords2;

 void main() {
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_texture1, v_texcoords1);
   vec4 color2 = texture2D(u_texture2, v_texcoords2);
   gl_FragColor = color1 * color2;  // multiply the colors.
 }
```

You then need to bind 2 textures to 2 texture units

```
 // bind a texture to texture unit0
 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);

 // bind a texture to texture unit1
 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, someOtherTexture);
```

And you need to tell the shader which texture units to use

```
 // -- at init time
 var texture1location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture1");
 var texture2location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture2");

 // -- at draw time

 // tell the shader to use texture units 0 and 1
 gl.uniform1i(texture1location, 0);
 gl.uniform1i(texture2location, 1);
```

But, that's generally NOT how to texture a cube with 6 images. Most games would texture a cube with 6 images by putting all 6 images in a single texture [(see end of this article)](http://greggman.github.io/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). Most 3D modeling programs would put 6 images on a cube by not making a cube but instead making 6 planes that each align to make the faces of a cube. In other words 6 individual plane models instead of one cube model. That way it stays simple. You just use a shader that draws 1 texture and use a different texture when drawing each plane of the cube.

In the game style case, 1 cube + 1 texture with 6 images. It's fast because there's just 1 draw call. In the 3d modeling package it 6 planes with 1 texture each (6 total) so 6 draw calls but it's flexible as each plane can use a different image without having to build a new texture with all 6 images in it.

Which way you choose is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

multiple texture units are used for multitexturing, for example when you blend together a dirt and grass texture to make dirty grass. see this example:

http://www.clockworkcoders.com/oglsl/tutorial8.htm

for what you are talking about (totally separate textures) it might make more sense to use a texture atlas (especially on embedded systems).  see section 3.9.4 here:

http://imgtec.eetrend.com/sites/imgtec.eetrend.com/files/download/201402/1462-2116-powervrdexingnengjianyi.pdf